# How can I cut a circular hole into this curvy shape?

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to recreate the PARTU air purifier below, but I have problems cutting a circula hole into the curvy body.

[image]

My approach is to model the curvy body first, then use a boolean circle to cut through it, like this:

[image]

But the result is a total mess:

[image]

What's the optimal way to make this shape in Blender?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it looks like the "crown" is a distinct part:

[image]

So I would create 2 different objects, and for the main part I would do it this way:

- Create your basic shape from a subdivided cube:

[image]

- Use the knife tool to cut (<kbd>K</kbd> to activate, <kbd>Z</kbd> to cut through)

[image]

- Press <kbd>V</kbd> to separate, delete the useless part.

[image]

- Mirror the shape, merge some vertices with <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>M</kbd> to keep a clean topology:

[image]

- Give your object a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, extrude the hole, add some edge loops to sharp the edges:

[image]

- Alternative topology (no triangle):

[image]

You could also use a *Shrinkwrap* modifier to get a different topology:

[image]

Comment: Thank a ton, moonboots. Your method is very clean. I'm trying to use extrusion as the main tool to create the shape, but it's far less optimal.

Comment: you could also use extrusion with a shrinkwrap but it doesn't seem useful here...

Comment: After trying this in Blender, I'll find it necessary to say thank you again. The Knife + Z is extremely powerful. You've saved me a ton of time for this and future modeling tasks. ~~

Comment: Also, with the knife, if you want to cut orthogonally, press C. And E to validate a cut and go on with a new one.

Comment: Yup. I know the knife + C and use it frequently. I have a question; I notice a triangle. Should we kill it for this mesh? I'm afraid it will cause some shading issue.

Comment: Triangles are ok as long as you don't see any artefacts, and I don't see any here

Comment: I've edited my answer with an alternative topology + shrinkwrap solution   ;)

Comment: You're very considerate, moon. I really appreciate your help. Somehow my brain doesn't think about using shrinkwrap to support the extrusion.

Comment: Hi moonboot, would you like to be my mentor? I want to speed up my modeling learning process, and I would love to learn from you. I can pay as well, as long as the rate is in my budget (which is not big because I'm trying to make a living with Blender).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98698/discussion-between-dng-hi-phng-and-moonboots).